# field extension-notation problem $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

let $K\subseteq L$ be a field extension and let $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$ also let $\alpha =\sqrt{2}$.

Then   $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$

What is the difference in the above notations? and why do we get them?

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}|a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

what is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is the smallest _subring_ of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is the smallest _subfield_ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. It turns out that for algebraic numbers, the smallest subring is a field, so the two coincide then. They are different for transcendental numbers, $\mathbb{Q}[\pi] \neq \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Great explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For fields $K \subset L$, and an $\alpha\in L$,

- $K[\alpha]$ denotes the smallest *subring* of $L$ that contains both $K$ and $\alpha$, and
- $K(\alpha)$ denotes the smallest *subfield* of $L$ that contains both $K$ and $\alpha$.

$K[\alpha]$ is the set of all polynomial expressions in $\alpha$,

$$K[\alpha] = \left\lbrace f(\alpha) : f \in K[X]\right\rbrace,$$

and $K(\alpha)$ is the set of all rational functions evaluated in $\alpha$ subject to the restriction that the denominator doesn't vanish in $\alpha$,

$$K(\alpha) = \left\lbrace \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} : f,g\in K[X],\, g(\alpha)\neq 0\right\rbrace.$$

It turns out that for algebraic $\alpha$, the two coincide, $K[\alpha] = K(\alpha)$. In fact, that is a necessary and sufficient condition, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$ if and only if $K[\alpha]$ is a field.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been after. Thanks